# Reference a property of the tag withing that same tag in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

in my application i have forms fields that dont have outside labels but use placeholders instead. Whta happend is when the fields are all filled out you cannot tell which field is what.

I was looking for a way to do smth like this(to display placeholder in a field title):

```
<input name="FirstName" title={this.element.getProperty('placeholder')} placeholder="First Name" />
```

Comment: You could use `ref`, but tell me... why would you?

Comment: @kinduser Because there is no space for labels within the component :( I understand it is simpler just to type in the title... but was looking for a better solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have multiple fields, right? Why not just to create a data which you would map over and create your inputs?

```
const data = [
   { name: "FirstName", title: "First Name" },
   { name: "LastName", title: "Last Name },
];
```

and then:

```
data.map((elem) => <input name={elem.name} title={elem.title} placeholder={elem.title} />);
```

Try to keep your life easier.

Comment: you are correct on multiples, but some of the fields have unique properties, and there are quite a few

Comment: @AnKing Unique properties? What's wrong with it? Just fill your data variable with these values and the `map` will do the rest

Comment: There's not enough of info in your post that I could try to suggest something else

Comment: I guess, I can still use the proposed suggestion, just combining a lodash _.slice() with different input fields